# cordova plugin nativegeocoder not defined

Tags: cordova, plugins, geocoding, html-framework-7

I am working on a mobile app with framework7 and cordova. After successfully using the geolocation plugin, I wanted to add the nativegeocoder, to translate coordinates into an address.

```
getAddress: function(){
      nativegeocoder.reverseGeocode(success, failure, 52.5072095, 13.1452818, { useLocale: true, maxResults: 1 });

      function success(result) {
        var firstResult = result[0];
        console.log("First Result: " + JSON.stringify(firstResult));
      }

      function failure(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

But I get on my console : ReferenceError: nativegeocoder is not defined .

Does anyone know how I can solve this? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error on console because browsers will not support this plugin.
Try to make the build of the app and run it on an android device or emulator.